# Как передать пустое значение поля? (Handlebars)

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars

```
res.render("login.hbs", {
    login: "",
    result: ""
});
```

в результате в поле login (input в форме) вводится /, вместо пустого значения
как ввести реально пустое значение в атрибут формы login?

Answer (score 0):

```
value="{{#if login}}{{login}}{{/if}}"
```